# How do I get my app to give me message "Net not connected" instead of crashing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, apache-httpclient-4.x

My app crashes, and I am unable to find the error.

I would like it to give me a message saying the network is not connected.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


 public class SimpleForm extends Activity {

private EditText editTextUserName;
private EditText editTextPassword;

//public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

String username;
String password;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registeration);

    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username_ID);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pass_ID);

}

public void invokeLogin(View view){
    username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
    password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();


    login(username,password);

}

private void login(final String username, String password) {

    class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        private Dialog loadingDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SimpleForm .this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //String uname = params[0];
           // String pass = params[1];


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("username", params[0]);
            } catch (JSONException e4) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("password", params[1]);
            } catch (JSONException e3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e3.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("deviceToken", "2324h5gj345gj3h4g5j");
            } catch (JSONException e5) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e5.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("os", "android");
            } catch (JSONException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                jsonObject.accumulate("key", "MEu07MgiuWgXwJOo7Oe1aHL0yM8P");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            String dataString = jsonObject.toString();



            //String dataString = {"username":"apitest","password":"123456","deviceToken":"2324h5gj345gj3h4g5j34g","os":"andriod","key":"MEu07MgiuWgXwJOo7Oe1aHL0yM8VvP"}
            InputStream is = null;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", dataString));
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
            String result = null;

            try{
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://mobile.betfan.com/api/?action=login");
                //http://mobile.betfan.com/api/?action=login
                //http://192.168.1.10/mobiletest/process.php
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            String s = result.trim();
            loadingDialog.dismiss();

                JSONObject respObject;
                try {
                    respObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    String active = respObject.getString("status_message");

                    if(active.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s+"Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent intent=new Intent(SimpleForm.this,Welcome.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                       // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                        //intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                       // finish();
                        //startActivity(intent);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        }
    }

    LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
    la.execute(username, password);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a method that will check whether a device has a network connection?

Comment: This question is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796001/prevent-app-from-crash-when-network-unavailable, review first answer, there you can find a method to detect network connectivity prior to launch your AsyncTask.

Comment: just it should give me message when net is not connected, and app should not go"unfortunately my-app has been stopped". only want that. @joshgoldeneagle

Comment: No part of your code checks for no network connection, so it is going to crash in `onPostExecute` at `result.trim();` because `result` will be null.

Comment: thankyou! @mbenegas your suggest tutorial lot off help me and i get solve my problem! thankyou you saved my life

Answer (score 2):

Before you use any code that requires network connectivity, you can call a method like this to check for connectivity:

```
private boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```